# Ellipsis plus width animation produces trembling

Tags: html, css, css-animations

During a recent implementation of a new label component, I got an issue which I never have seen before.

This label component has to display the first letter on repose. If the label is being hovered, the width will be increased being animated in order to display the full text. If the final full text is too long, an ellipsis should cut it.

The issue is when the label is being hovered the ellipsis calculation + width animation + innerText change produces a terrible trembling.

Here the example code, just hover the label component.

**NOTE:** In this example I am using custom elements feature, make sure you are using a compatible browser.

```js
class LabelComponent extends HTMLElement {
  short = 'A';
  long = 'A very long item name';
  _eventSet = new Set();
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.innerText = this.short;
    this._eventSet.add({
      trigger: 'mouseenter',
      callback: () => {
        this.innerText = this.long;
      }
    });
    this._eventSet.add({
      trigger: 'mouseleave',
      callback: () => {
        this.innerText = this.short;
      }
    });
  }

  _registerEvents() {
    this._unRegisterEvents();
    for (let eventItem of this._eventSet) {
      this.addEventListener(eventItem.trigger, eventItem.callback);
    }
  }

  _unRegisterEvents() {
    for (let eventItem of this._eventSet) {
      this.removeEventListener(eventItem.trigger, eventItem.callback);
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this._registerEvents();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    this._unRegisterEvents();
  }
}


customElements.define('label-component', LabelComponent);
```

```css
label-component {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: width 0.35s ease;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

label-component:hover {
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<label-component></label-component>
```

Do any ideas for fixing this issue?

Comment: That seems to be mainly due to `text-align:center`, as soon as you leave it at `left`, the effect appears to be mostly gone.

Comment: @04FS thanks for having a look, I am gonna check it right now. Please add your comment like an answer in order to continue the conversation below your answer :muscle:

Comment: @04FS Thanks again. I have checked it. It is very interesting how `text-align:center` is producing this issue. Unfortunately  `text-align:center` is a requirement for short texts. Probably I have to re-think the component HTML structure to allow all requirements.

Comment: Tried an answer that had the text content wrapped into an additional span, but forgot to transport the text-overflow and white-space properties onto that one ... after moving those to the span, the effect was the same again :-/

Comment: @04FS please add your first comment as an answer to make it more visible. +1